# How can I add a custom header to a HTTP request (Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, header

I have a HTTP request that looks like this:

```
payload = someObject;
$.post(webHost+':'+webPort+'\\login\\'+payload, function(response){
});
```

How can I add a custom header to the HTTP request?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass HTTP headers via `$.post()`.

But if you want to using `$.post` method add below codes :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

Comment: So, if I wanted to send a username and sessionID to the server, could I put these custom variables in the headers object?